# ffmpeg returns "no such process" error when called by cron

Tags: linux, cron, permissions

I have an .sh script to record hourly from the sound card

```
 #!/bin/bash

if ps -efa | grep -v grep | grep ffm | grep /home/user/auto-record > /dev/null
then
    echo running
    exit
else
   /usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -f pulse -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo -loglevel fatal -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 3600 -segment_atclocktime 1 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k /home/user/auto-record/%Y-%m-%d/rec_%H-%M-%>
fi
```

It checks if there is a ffmpeg running and if not, start recording. I have set it up as a cronjob in crontab every minute

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/user/autoRec.sh
```

But it returns me error

```
alsa_input.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo: No such process
```

If I just run it as **/home/user/autoRec.sh** it works as expected. What Am I missing?

**SOLVED**

apparently

- adding one, or more, of these lines at the beginning of the script
- running it as a root

solved this issue

```
/home/USERNAME/.bashrc
/home/USERNAME/.profile

export PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH="/run/user/$(id -u)/pulse/"
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$(id -u)"


PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```